# Factorial and induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Part of step in induction:

$(2 k+1)*((1*3* 5*\dotsb* (2k-1)) =1*3*5*\dotsb*(2k+1)$

Am I correct with believing that we in first instance went up to $k$, and then we went further to $2((k+1)-1$ hence the last expression?

Comment: What is the statement you are trying to prove? This question is so out of context I don't think anyone knows what you are asking...

Comment: Isn't this simply the commutativity and associativity of multplication?

Comment: Did you mean that you went up to $k$ in the expression $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5  \cdots (2k - 1)$ and up to $k + 1$ in the expression $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2k - 1) \cdot (2k + 1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to write that is

\begin{align*}
\left[\prod_{i=1}^k (2i-1)\right]\times(2k+1) 
&= \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} (2i-1) \\
&= 1\cdot3\cdot5\dotsb(2(k-1)-1)\cdot(2(k)-1)\cdot(2(k+1)-1)\\
&= 1\cdot3\cdot5\dotsb(2k-2-1)\cdot(2k-1)\cdot(2k+2-1)\\
&= 1\cdot3\cdot5\dotsb(2k-3)\cdot(2k-1)\cdot(2k+1)
\end{align*}

This way you can see/say that it "goes to $k+1$". So, yes, you are correct in believing that.